# How can I add an object to my firestore from the frontend with react? Keep getting the error Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add an object to my firestore that looks like this:
][image: The Object in Firestore]

This is the code where I add the object:

```
updateDoc(usersRef, { //adding username to users field in firestore
                users: arrayUnion({ username: "yeah", items: items })
            })
```

If I need this object in this specific way how else can I do this? Does anyone have any ideas?

I tried looking around and there are similar posts but they are mostly by mistake and not people needing actual objects.

Comment: Are you trying to update an item in an array? If so, that is not possible with the Firestore API. All it can do is add a new item to an array (with `arrayUnion` as the code in your question does), or remove items from an array (with `arrayRemove`). If you want to update an existing item, you'll have to: 1) Read the array from the document, 2) Update it in your application code, 3) Write the entire array back to the database.

Comment: Yeah I'm not trying to update it I'm just trying to add a new item, but my only problem is I want to add an object like I showed above {{username:"yeah"}, items:items}} but React doesn't let me do this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. "React doesn't let me do this" is not easy to help with though. Why not? Is there an error message?

Comment: Yeah it says "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" but if I'm not able to pass an object then how can I possibly do this?

Comment: That error message comes from React, but the code you shared contains nothing specific to React (which is why I removed the tag). Please edit your question (there's a link right under there) to include the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child` means you are trying to render an object in your jsx. You can only render one property at at at time.

```
<div>{user.username}</div>
{user.items.map((item)=>(
    <div>{item}</div>
))
```

**assuming each "item" is one value (i.e. string or number etc..)

Furthermore firestore [updateDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en&authuser=0#update-data) takes a ref as its first argument and the object as is second.

You already have the ref `usersRef` which I think a collection not a document, but ***I believe*** that firestore will add a document anyway, so just add the object (without any arrayUnion).
assuming items is an array then boom!

```
// const usersRef = collection(firestore, "users")
await updateDoc(usersRef, { username: "yeah", items: items })
```

firestore will add an id automatically.

Technically you should be updating by getting a ref for a particular document first and using `setDoc()` for creating

```
const usersRef = collection(firestore, "users")

// This is create new document
const newDoc = await setDoc(usersRef, {username: "yeah", items: items})

// This will update only properties you include in the object
const userRef = doc(usersRef, {newDoc.id})
await updateDoc(usersRef, {items: newItems})
```